# To display full screen Image

Tags: android, gridview

I have images stored in sdcard and I am displaying it in gridview,Now I want to show the fullscreen image on gridview OnItemCLick Listener.I am not getting the Fullscreen Image on next screen.Only blank screen showing.

```
 public class MyMenu extends Activity{
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c; 
        }
        void add(String path){
            itemList.add(path); 
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return itemList.size();
        }
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return null;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90, 70));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 90, 70);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            return imageView;
        }
        public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

            Bitmap bm = null;
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 
            return bm;   
        }

        public int calculateInSampleSize(

                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                if (width > height) {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);    
                } else {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);    
                }   
            }
            return inSampleSize;    
        }
    }
    ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    ImageButton camera,lib,baby,info;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymenu);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent i5=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullScreenSd.class);
                i5.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i5);
            }
        });
        myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/temp/");
        if (folder.exists()) {
            String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath();
            String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/temp/";
            File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
            File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
            for (File file : files){
                myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } 
        }
```

and Receiving class is,

```
image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int resId = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        image.setImageResource(resId);
```

Comment: So what is your problem ? Please specify your problem clearly.

Comment: why you are setting position as resource ID?

Comment: I dont know How to show fullscreen Image when clicked on gridview Item.I thought setting position might work,thats why I have set position to image view.

Comment: @user1758835 Please post your full activity code, so we can help you more.

Comment: @user1758835 Please see my answer and if you have any issue then tell me or if my answer is helping you then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
i5.putExtra("id", position);
```

and

```
image.setImageResource(resId);
```

What exactly are you doing here? position is it's position in the gridview. Why did you take it as id?

Answer (score 0):

The part where you do `i5.putExtra("id", position);` is the position of the element that was clicked. That's not what you need, you need the resId of the item clicked. Assuming you have the resIds stored in some array, you should pass `i5.putExtra("id", resIdArray[position]);`

Answer (score 0):

There are four solution of this problem but first two solution is proper.

1) Convert Bitmap into Byte Array and then pass into activity.

Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Pass byte array into intent:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

2) First Save Selected image into internal or external memory and then get image into next activity and display in full screen.

3) Pass Image Url to next activity and then download image again in Full screen activity and then display in imageview.

4) Pass bitmap into activity.(But If your image size is too large at that time this solution is not working)